# How to finally and completely disable hibernate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a Spring Boot project that is not using JPA/Hibernate (but which cannot help but have these libraries on the classpath; long story, but completely unchangeable in this context), I need to stop whatever autoconfiguration is causing the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

I am aware that I have to explicitly exclude JPA/Hibernate autoconfiguration. I do so in both the `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated Java class and also in the `application.properties` file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com" })
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
}
```

and

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Additionally, I've verified that these autoconfigurations are being excluded, by looking in the `--debug` output:

```
Exclusions:
-----------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Still, it fails when I don't have a JPA `@Entity` defined.

Why would this be?

Comment: If you don't use it, why is it that you cannot exclude the dependencies (or make them optional)?

Comment: Bureaucracy... :(

Comment: Which is a very bad reason... Instead of actually solving the issue you are trying to workaround in, and even worse have a lot of stuff on your class path you don't use/need.

Comment: agreed, but nothing I can do about it. Well, partially agreed. SpringBoot is an opinionated framework. It assumes that, if data-jpa is on the path, that you want to use it. It is entirely reasonable, and not a hack or a workaround, to expect that you can override that opinion.

Comment: You can but why put something on the class path you don't intend to use.

Comment: There is a parent Maven project that I have to use (security policy), which includes it. I temporarily solved the issue by excluding it from the transient dependencies. I just don't really like that as a solution.

Comment: You shouldn't include stuff you don't need imho else disable all auto configuration. Post the full error / stack trace / output you get instead of a single line and you probably also need disable the `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` (although I guess that is also driven by the existence of an `EntityManagerFactory`.).